# Poles with complex multiplicity

Tags: complex-analysis

I just wasn't able to find anything on this.
But how do you treat functions which have poles with complex multiplicity?
For example:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z)^{ik+1}}$$

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does **not** have a pole at $z=-1$ (unless $k=0$). In fact, $z=-1$ is not even an isolated singularity of $f$. There is no way to define $f$ holomorphically on a punctured neighbourhood of $z=-1$.

Comment: The OP has posted an answer which contradicts yours. Would you mind expanding on your answer or pointing out why the other answer in incorrect?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Actually, I posted this when I saw the OP's own attempt. From the formula in the other answer, $$ f(z) = \exp(-(1+ik)\log(1+z)) $$ and there is no way to define $\log$ as a holomorphic (or even continuous) function on a punctured neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think they way to about this particular problem is to use the definition of a complex logarithm.
Put $(1+z)^{ik}=e^y$ such that $y=ik\,log(1+z)$
Then the expression reduces to:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^{iklog(1+z)}(1+z)}$$
So it has a pole at $z=-1$.

Comment: Note that your claim that $z = -1$ is a pole is false. See mrf's answer and comment.